# List Python Operation

Tags: python, list

I got this list:

```
input = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]]
```

I want to make new lists with each index item:

i.e.

```
output = [[1,5,9],[2,6,10],[3,7,11],[4,8,12]]
```

Comment: RTM: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions

Answer (score 8):

This is a canonical example of when to use [zip](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip):

```
In [6]: inlist = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]]

In [7]: out=zip(*inlist)

In [8]: out
Out[8]: [(1, 5, 9), (2, 6, 10), (3, 7, 11), (4, 8, 12)]
```

Or, to get a list of lists (rather than list of tuples):

```
In [9]: out=[list(group) for group in zip(*inlist)]

In [10]: out
Out[10]: [[1, 5, 9], [2, 6, 10], [3, 7, 11], [4, 8, 12]]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `zip()`:

```
input = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]]
output = zip(*input)
```

This will give you a list of tuples.  To get a list of lists, use

```
output = map(list, zip(*input))
```